# How to sort values from echo command output?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sort

I have a command

```
pr -m   <(echo -n "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)" |
    runmqsc UFISMQ |grep QUEUE |
    awk '{print $1}' |
    cut -c6-100) <(echo -ne "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)" |
    runmqsc UFISMQ |grep IPPROCS |
    cut -c11-15 |sed "1 d") |
    awk 'NR>=6&&NR<=13' |
```

this command helps me find the number of  applications connected to the MQ queues. Output is this

```
(SYSTEM.BROKER.CONTROL.QUEUE)       (3)
(TO_UFIS)                           (18)
(UFIS_ATC_IN)                       (2)
(UFIS_BELT_IN)                      (2)
(UFIS_COUNTER_IN)                   (2)
(UFIS_FLIGHT_IN)                    (2)
(UFIS_OTHERS_IN)                    (2)
(UFIS_TRIGGER_IN)                   (2)
```

**problem**

Now I to want to sort the output and trigger a mail alert only when one of the values is `(0)`. which means no application is connected to MQ.

how can I sort the above output to find `(0)` value?

Comment: Why do you perform two queries? How do you know they return identical data? Can't you do the selection of the attributes you want to see in the MQ query itself?

Comment: Also, wouldn't you be able to use `runmqsc` with a query that simply returns a list of queues with no connections? Maybe something that parses the output of something like `DISPLAY QSTATUS(*) ALL` or similar MQ query?

Answer (score 1):

You can `grep` the (0) value to trigger your mail and use the command `sort` to sort output on specific column  output.

For example:

```
df -h | sort -nk5
```

will do a "numeric" (not lexicographical) sort on key 5, which is `Use%`.